Implemented syscall but getting "Function not implemented" error
Trying to implemented syscall in kernel space and wrapper in glibc so I can call from userspace.
When I call the function call in user program it says "Function not implemented".
I have modified glibc and linux code to add function called vroperation.
In GLIBC:
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:26:#ifndef __NR_vroperation
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:36:#define __NR_vroperation 285
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:40:#define __NR_vroperation  338
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/syscall.h:44:#endif  /* __NR_vroperation */
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list:91:vroperation  -       vroperation     i:iii   __vroperation   vroperation
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/generic/vroperation.c:25:__vroperation (int vr_index, int oper, int flags)
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/generic/vroperation.c:30:stub_warning (vroperation)
glibc/srcdir/sysdeps/generic/vroperation.c:32:weak_alias (__vroperation, vroperation)
glibc/srcdir/conform/data/unistd.h-data:603:function int vroperation(int, int, int);
glibc/srcdir/include/unistd.h:198:extern int __vroperation(int __vr_index, int __oper, int __flags);
glibc/srcdir/posix/unistd.h:686:extern int vroperation (int __vr_index, int __oper, int __flags) __THROW;
glibc/srcdir/posix/Versions:111:    vroperation;
glibc/srcdir/posix/Makefile:180:  vroperation \
glibc/srcdir/posix/annexc.c:544:  "ttyname_r", "unlink", "vroperation", "write"


In LINUX:
arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl:361:338  64      vroperation             __x64_sys_vroperation
arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl:300:285  i386    vroperation             sys_vroperation                 __ia32_sys_vroperation
kernel/sys.c:2527:SYSCALL_DEFINE3(vroperation, int, vr_index, int, oper, int, flags)
kernel/sys_ni.c:185:COND_SYSCALL(vroperation);

When I run Strace:
execve("/tmp/vroperation", ["/tmp/vroperation", "delete", "0"], 0x7fffaa0d51e0 /* 23 vars */) = 0
/tmp/strace: [ Process PID=19284 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x9e63000
brk(0x9e63880)                          = 0x9e63880
set_thread_area({entry_number=-1, base_addr=0x9e63380, limit=0x0fffff, seg_32bit=1, contents=0, read_exec_only=0, limit_in_pages=1, seg_not_present=0, useable=1}) = 0 (entry_number=12)
set_tid_address(0x9e633e8)              = 19284
set_robust_list(0x9e633ec, 12)          = 0
rseq(0x9e63820, 0x20,
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/exe", "/var/tmp/vroperation", 4096) = 20
getrandom("\xbd\x59\x2c\xbd", 4, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 4
brk(NULL)                               = 0x9e63880
brk(0x9e84880)                          = 0x9e84880
brk(0x9e85000)                          = 0x9e85000
mprotect(0x80d9000, 12288, PROT_READ)   = 0
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
statx(3, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_BASIC_STATS, {stx_mask=STATX_BASIC_STATS, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFCHR|0622, stx_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(3, "vroperation: Function not implem"..., 38vroperation: Function not implemented
) = 38
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0x9e84000)                          = 0x9e84000
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++


Trying to implement syscall in kernel and wraper in glibc which can be called in userspace.
